Retrieving Access Packages and Resources in a Catalog with PowerShell
I’m a new member here. I’m currently exploring how to retrieve all the access packages from a specific catalog, as well as possibly gather all the resources utilized there. My initial step is to enumerate all the access packages within a specific catalog, but it seems to be not functioning as expected.
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "EntitlementManagement.ReadWrite.All

#Define the catalog name

$catalogName = "Test"

#Get the catalog ID

$catalogId = (Get-MgEntitlementManagementCatalog | Where-Object { $\_.DisplayName -eq $catalogName }).Id

#Get all access packages

$accessPackages = Get-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackage

#Filter access packages under the catalog

$filteredAccessPackages = $accessPackages | Where-Object { $\_.CatalogId -eq $catalogId }

#List all access packages

$filteredAccessPackages | Format-Table Id, DisplayName, Description

Already tried several cmdlets/commands but not working.

By default it doesn't always get all properties
$accessPackages = Get-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackage -All -ExpandProperty Catalog $filteredAccessPackages = $accessPackages | Where-Object { $_.Catalog.Id -eq $catalogId }
